# Components not entering a new line when no space with flowlayout?

Tags: java, flowlayout

Flowlayout supposedly whenever a component is added and there is no space left on the current line starts a new line, however this is not working for me and the components are just going on and being cut out just like this picture :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbaud.png

What I think you might need to know:

1. The size of the frame is 800x600.
2. I made it not resizable with setResizable(false).

Comment: Any code to start with ?

Comment: @Sanjeev i don't get why you need code lol all i would post is setLayout(new FlowLayout()) lol.